# How to change api version in HTTPUtlis?

Tags: java, api, http, versioning

Let's assume, that I have some client library with HttpUtils class inside it. And it has field API_VERSION

```
public class HttpUtils {

    public static final int API_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json";

    private final CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    // Public HTTP request methods

    public <Request extends HttpGetRequest, Response> Response
    get(ConnectionConfig config, String endpoint,
        Request request, Map<String, String> requestHeaders,
        ResponseHandler<Request, Response> handler, int expectedStatusCode) {
        return get(config, endpoint, request, Defaults.DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT, requestHeaders, handler, expectedStatusCode);
    }


    private static String getEndpointURI(String endpoint) {
        return "/" + UrlParameters.API_SERVICE +
                "/" + UrlParameters.VERSION_PREFIX + API_VERSION +
                "/" + endpoint;
    }
```

And also I have third-party API that I want to call using this client, but the API is updated and now they using API_VERSION = 2 for some new endpoints. How correctly extend from HTTPUtils and have ability to use both versions for my third-party API calls with v1 and v2 versions?

Comment: You can send API_VERSION's variable in method's parameters

Comment: HttpUtils is a library class and I can't change it

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method that let's you override the version and don't make it final.

```
public static int API_VERSION = 1;

private static String getEndpointURI(String endpoint, String apiVersion) {

    if (apiVersion != null) {
       API_VERSION = apiVersion;
    }
    return "/" + UrlParameters.API_SERVICE +
           "/" + UrlParameters.VERSION_PREFIX + API_VERSION +
           "/" + endpoint;
}
```

Something like that anyway.

Comment: HttpUtils is a library class and I can't change it :(